# Spark session is not getting initialized | sparkR.session() gives the error "Error in if (len > 0) { : argument is of length zero"

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, sparkr, databricks-connect

I am currently using Rstudio server hosted outside databricks cluster and followed the steps to configure Databricks Connect. The connection test was also successful . But when I initialize a spark session using the below code, it throws up an error.

```
>>library(SparkR)
>>sparkR.session()
```

I have even tried the command below but throws up the same error:

```
SparkR::sparkR.session()
```

**WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
Error in if (len > 0) { : argument is of length zero**

I want to access SQL tables on databricks or write an sql query in R like below:

```
diamonds <- sql("select * from default.diamonds")
```

for which initializing spark session is required. Let me know if any other alternative can be applied.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I made the following changes to my code.

```
library(SparkR, lib.loc = "/usr/local/spark/R/lib")
sparkEnvir <- list(spark.num.executors='5', spark.executor.cores='5')
# initializing Spark context
sc <- sparkR.init(sparkHome = "/usr/local/spark",
                  sparkEnvir = sparkEnvir)
# initializing SQL context
sqlContext <- sparkRSQL.init(sc)
```